# Automation of splitting excel sheets based on column values with Python

Tags: python, excel, automation

Consider I have a huge excel sheet, with multiple columns and entries. However, there exists a particular column (COLUMN A) containing boolean values 0s and 1s. Now I wish to split my parent excel sheet into 2 sheets, based on the values of the COLUMN A. I already know that this can be done using VBA codes. However, I wanna try this on python.
My idea is that we can iterate through the said column values, and if a condition is satisfied, pick up the whole row and write it in a new sheet.
I am learning the language, can use numpy and pandas a bit to create linear regression models and the like. I'd like to work on this 'personal-project'. Would be glad if anyone would help me with this, provide a few hints or something to start with. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How I would go about it:

1. Read the full excel sheet into a pandas dataframe
   `df = pd.from_excel("file_name.xlsx")`
2. Filter the dataframe by values in that columns

```
df1 = df[df["COLUMN A"]==1]
df0 = df[df["COLUMN A"]==0]
```

3. Read those new dataframes to a new excel workbook, or new excel sheet on an exisiting workbook, using the pandas ExcelWriter: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html

Don't forget to handle missing data in column A, if there is any.

I am just a student, so perhaps there are more efficient ways to do this, but I use pandas quite a bit in my undergraduate research and this is what I would do. Best of luck you :)

Comment: wow thank you. Also, I wanted to know if it's possible to make it real time? like as I'm entering the values 0 and 1, they are being split in those 2 sheets?

Comment: @YamiKanashi I believe that would require it to be done through VBA as Python cannot access the file if something else has it open.

Comment: seems there is a way, in python's xlwings module you can work and run python codes simultaneously, the best way to do your task is to have 3 sheets in your workbook 2 sheet save data and 1 to write data from user. Add your column A at last that specifies whether it goes to Sheet 1 or Sheet 2 if Column A entry is 0 take the whole row paste it to Sheet 0 else entry is 1 paste it to Sheet 2